# Error when trying to erase vector of pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, erase

Lets say I have a vector of class pointers Tower like this:

```
vector<Tower*> tower_list;
```

I have done a couple operations to add Towers into my vector but now when I try to use the vector::erase method like this

```
tower_list.erase(0);
```

I get the following error message:

```
Error: no instance of overloaded function "std::vector<_ty, _Alloc>::erase[with _Ty=Tower*, _Allow=std:allocator<Tower*>]" matches the argument list argument types are: (int)
object type is: std::vector<Tower*, std::alocator<Tower*>>
```

Can anyone explain why I am receiving this compile error when trying to erase this tower pointer? Let me know if you need more details. Thanks

Comment: `tower_list.erase(tower_list.begin());` - please look at a documentation of std::vector

Comment: @DieterLücking This seems to work. Why can't I simply put the index? And what if I don't want to delete the first element?

Comment: You can add an offset to the iterator.  (e.g. tower_list.erase(tower_list.begin()+2);)

Comment: Thanks guys. Can someone tell me if this will delete the actual Tower object or the pointer?

Comment: Please refer to documentation about the erase method. the argument is an iterator to be erased or a range of iterators.   http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/

Comment: It will NOT delete the tower pointed to. Use `vector<unique_ptr<Tower>>` if you want objects pointed to, to be deleted automatically when they are removed from the vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vector::erase` takes an `iterator`, not an integer.

So if you want to erase the first element in the vector:

```
tower_list.erase (tower_list.begin());
```

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase

Answer (score 1):

From [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase), these are the overloaded `erase` functions defined on `std::vector`.

```
iterator erase( iterator pos );
iterator erase( const_iterator pos );
iterator erase( iterator first, iterator last );
iterator erase( const_iterator first, const_iterator last );
```

The argument `0` cannot be converted to any of the argument types in the two overloads that take one argument.

If you want to erase the item containing a NULL pointer, use:

```
std::vector<Tower*>::iterator iter = tower_list.find(nullptr);
if ( iter != tower_list.end() )
{
   tower_list.erase(iter);
}
```